# how to console.log in shopfiy .liquid code

Tags: url, shopify, liquid

how can I see the console.log in the browser console. In mini-cart.liquid I did:

console.log({{request.origin}})

but can't see it in the console.

Comment: You're missing ''. `<script>console.log('{{request.origin}}');</script>`

Comment: thanks but I did include the tags. Just didn't include them here. So still not working. Is it because mini-cart is limiting access to some objects?

Comment: @Seb it's really hard to tell why it's not working without knowing the context. Can you describe the problem and share the code, not just a single line? mini-cart.liquid can be anything

Answer (score 0):

unlike the "product" object, the "request" one can't be logged like that because it's server-side.

The product object can be logged like that:

```
console.log({{ product | json }});
```

But, for the request you have to do a little trick where you render the request as text in your frontend:

```
{{ request.origin }}
```

Be careful to do that on your local version and always remove it before pushing anything :)